# Python Background Processes On Windows. Caps-lock app

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tkinter, subprocess

I've been trying to write a small application (in python2.7) which wouldn't use much CPU memory or slow down the computer whilst running in the background (as a sub-process?). All it's suppose to do is display a message in the top right corner which states if it's "ON". And if it's not on, just close/don't display the message. Sounds pretty simple, but I can't seem to get it.

The end result I would like it to run when the computer starts up. Maybe use a .batch file which automatically runs the python script, however I think I will need to go into some processing coding for it to work efficiently.

This is the code I have so far, I recently added the while loop which makes it able to see the pop up window, however it doesn't close it when caps-lock is off. And I'm almost certain it could be done more 'neatly'?

Thanks for any help in advance!

The main code (capsLock.py);

---

```
import win32api, win32con
from Tkinter import *

class CapsLock(object):

    def __init__(self, window):

        window.resizable(FALSE,FALSE)
        window.geometry('100x20-5+5')

        # return 1 if CAPSLOCK is ON
        if win32api.GetKeyState(win32con.VK_CAPITAL) == 1:
            self.canvas = Canvas(window, bg ="white", height=20, width=20)
            self.canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

            self.lock = Label(self.canvas, text="Caps Lock Is ON")
            self.lock.pack()

            window.attributes("-topmost", True)

        else:
            window.destroy()


def main():
    while(1):
        root = Tk()
        app = CapsLock(root)
        root.mainloop()

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Below is the code which I initially tried to run it as a sub-process (CapsStart.py);

---

```
import sys
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "capsLock.py"])
print proc.returncode
```

---

Sorry for using the '_' to display the code snippets, not so familiar with stackoverflow.

Louis.

**UPDATE**
So I've added a delay as well as update to the code and moved the while loop. This seemed to work, but not for long. After running it with caps-lock being on and then switching it off works but when I switch capslock back on it throws a TclError. I tried catching it and just making it continue. But yeah It doesn't seem to work. Any further help would be appreciated. (I'd like to write my own caps-lock indicator instead of downloading someone elses). The error and new code is below;

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Louis\Documents\PyGames\Learning\capsLock.py", line 42, in 
    main()

File "C:\Users\Louis\Documents\PyGames\Learning\capsLock.py", line 38, in main
    app = CapsLock(root)

File "C:\Users\Louis\Documents\PyGames\Learning\capsLock.py", line 17, in **init**
    self.canvas = Canvas(window, bg ="white", height=20, width=20)

File "C:\python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2195, in **init**
    Widget.**init**(self, master, 'canvas', cnf, kw)

File "C:\python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2055, in **init**
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))

_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "canvas" command:  application has been destroyed
[Finished in 4.3s]

```
import win32api, win32con
from Tkinter import *
import time

class CapsLock(object):

    def __init__(self, window):

        window.resizable(FALSE,FALSE)
        window.geometry('100x20-5+5')

        while(1):
            time.sleep(0.3)

            # return 1 if CAPSLOCK is ON
            if win32api.GetKeyState(win32con.VK_CAPITAL) == 1:
                self.canvas = Canvas(window, bg ="white", height=20, width=20)
                self.canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

                self.lock = Label(self.canvas, text="Caps-Lock Is ON")
                self.lock.pack()
                window.update()

                window.attributes("-topmost", True)

            else:  
                try :
                    window.destroy()
                    window.update()

                except TclError:
                    continue


def main():

    root = Tk()
    app = CapsLock(root)
    root.mainloop()

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You seem to keep creating and destroying your windows as fast as you can (see `while 1`). You need to create the window once and wait for events. Probably the easiest variant is some kind of timer (`time.sleep()`) that periodically checks the caps lock state. I don't think Tk is the best tool for the job. Take a look e.g. at [this open-source utility](http://www.georgejopling.co.uk/capslock/capslock.html) that does about what you want. Try to read the source (disclaimer: I didn't).

Comment: To me it looks good. I must agree with 9000. The two things I would change is to put the wile loop around the if and use root.update().